# How to authenticate user in keycloak using challenge response system while using its admin api

Tags: rest, authentication, keycloak, challenge-response

i m using keycloak 8.0 and i m looking to authenticate user by calling it admin api. Below is the curl command .

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quickstart-serv-springboot/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: abf5c8bf-0d1f-4178-951d-ba6c9d385596' \
  -d 'client_id=wb-auth-url-demo&username=admin-wb-auth-url-demo&password=admin&grant_type=password&client_secret=a3ffca99-e0b7-49d2-8369-b9eb15385b60'
```

This approach looks at sending password in clear text to keycloak server but i m looking to use challenge response system which comapres hashvalue of the password for the user. How can i do this using the admin apis ?

Comment: Why you can't use standard authorization code flow?

Comment: @JanGaraj Can you give me more details or example ? I need to call this from  a NodeJS or Kong or Spring boot service